# Functional Gaussian Integral

Tags: calculus

I am trying to reproduce the result below

$$\int\mathcal{D}V~e^{-\int dx~[a V^{2}(x)+iV(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt~ \bar{\psi}^{a}(x,t)\gamma_{ab}\psi^{b}(x,t)]}= e^{-\frac{1}{4a}\int dx\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt dt'(\bar{\psi}^{a}(x,t)\psi^{a}(x,t))(\bar{\psi}^{b}(x,t')\psi^{b}(x,t'))}$$
Where $\gamma_{ab}$ is a $2\times 2$ identity matrix and $\psi\bar{\psi}=-\bar{\psi}\psi$ are Grassman variables and $a$ is a constant.

I tried to reproduce it but could not succeed. Any comments or suggestions are welcome. I am new in this site, I would request not to close or downvote this question.

Here is my attempt:
Let $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt~\bar{\psi}^{a}(x,t)\gamma_{ab}\psi^{b}(x,t)$. Then we can write

$$\int\mathcal{D}V~e^{-\int dx~[a V^{2}(x)+iV(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt~ \bar{\psi}^{a}(x,t)\gamma_{ab}\psi^{b}(x,t)]} = \int\mathcal{D}V~e^{-\int dx~[a V^{2}(x)+iV(x)f(x)]}$$
Completing the square gives, $[aV^{2}(x)+iV(x)f(x)]=a(V+\frac{if}{2a})^{2}+\frac{f^{2}}{4a}$. Then
$$\int\mathcal{D}V~e^{-\int dx~[a V^{2}(x)+iV(x)f(x)}=e^{-\frac{f^{2}}{4a}}\int\mathcal{D}V~e^{-\int~dr V^{2}(r)dr}
$$
I got the factor $e^{-\frac{f^{2}}{4a}}$ and the integral $\int\mathcal{D}V~e^{-\int~dr V^{2}(r)dr}$ gives a constant contribution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question should include more details and clarify the problem. Also show your idea to solve the problem and also indicate where you stuck.

Comment: @ nmasanta, Thank you for your advice, I am it editing accordingly.